# Checkbox and Radio buttons are not working

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm creating a customized radio button and checkbox button, all seems fine and the css looks great however the problem is the buttons doesn't seem to be working. When i click on a radio button or a checkbox, it does not detect is as the new checked button. Can anyone help me on identifying the problem?

CODE:

```css
/** SIZE MODAL BUTTONS **/
.prod-desk-size-container {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding-left: 45pt;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.prod-desk-size-container input {
 position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gold-check {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: solid 1px #d9d9d9;
}

.gold-check:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.prod-desk-size-container input:checked ~ .gold-check {
    background-image: url('../images/icon-selected.png');
 background-size: 100%;
    border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade show" id="modal-desk-product" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title">HAWAIIAN</h5><br>
     <p class="modal-desc">Ham, pineapple,corn and mozzarella cheese</p>
     <div class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-body mb-2">
          <h6 class="modal-desk-product-title font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-left">What size are you after?</h6>
     <hr>
                <div class="prod-desk-size row text-left" id="prod-desk-size" data-toggle="buttons">
         <label class="prod-desk-size-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Small
                               <input type="radio" name="prod-desk-size-radio" checked>
                               <span class="gold-check rounded-circle"></span>
                           </label>
         
         <label class="prod-desk-size-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Medium
                               <input type="radio" name="prod-desk-size-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check rounded-circle"></span>
                           </label>
         
         <label class="prod-desk-size-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Large
                               <input type="radio" name="prod-desk-size-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check rounded-circle"></span>
                           </label>
         
         <label class="prod-desk-size-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Seriously Large
                               <input type="radio" name="prod-desk-size-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check rounded-circle"></span>
                           </label>
      </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Insert this css

```
.prod-desk-del-container{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding-left: 45pt;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Hope this help.

Let me know further clearification.

```css
                        /** DELETE INGREEDIENT MODAL BUTTONS **/
.prod-desk-del-container {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    padding-left: 45pt;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.prod-desk-del-container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.gold-check-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.prod-desk-del-container input:checked ~ .gold-check-box {
    background-color: #b79469;
    background-image: url('../images/icon-check-white.png');
    background-size: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 2px 6px;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.gold-check-box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<h6 class="modal-desk-product-title font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-left pt-4">Would you like any extra ingredients?</h6>
                      <hr>
                        <div class="prod-desk-del row text-left" id="prod-desk-del" data-toggle="buttons">
                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Eggs <span class="price">+$10.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Side of portion of Beef Ribs <span class="price">+$10.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Side of portion of Pork Ribs <span class="price">+$15.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Bacon Onion Jam <span class="price">+$15.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Prawn Top <span class="price">+$9.95</span?>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Grilled Onions <span class="price">+$9.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Bloomin' Oion Petals <span class="price">+$15.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">King Island Roaring Forties <span class="price">+$15.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Sauteed Mushrooms <span class="price">+$15.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Mayonnaise<span class="price">+$10.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>

                           <label class="prod-desk-del-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Pineapple <span class="price">+$15.95</span>
                               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="prod-desk-side-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check-box rounded"></span>
                           </label>
                        </div>
```

Comment: it seems that it is still not working for me. i placed these buttons inside a modal, will that affect the code?

Comment: Can you please add your code into snippet ?. So i can understand what you want to do.

Comment: i added the snippet in the original post, hope you can help out

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the parent (`<label>`) `position:relative`:

```
.prod-desk-del-container {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    padding-left: 45pt;
    position: relative; // Add this
}
```

Also as a side note, semantically an `<input>` shouldn't be inside a `<label>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be use this style

```
.prod-desk-size-container input:checked ~ .gold-check {
    background-image: url('../images/icon-selected.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

**And the reason is**

When you checked your radio button there you give `.prod-desk-size-container input:checked ~ .gold-check{border:0;}`

So please give any color and border as your requirement into this class-> `.prod-desk-size-container input:checked ~ .gold-check`

Hope this help

Let me know further clarification.

```css
 /** SIZE MODAL BUTTONS **/
.prod-desk-size-container {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding-left: 45pt;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.prod-desk-size-container input {
 position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gold-check {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: solid 1px #d9d9d9;
}

.gold-check:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.prod-desk-size-container input:checked ~ .gold-check {
    background-image: url('../images/icon-selected.png');
 background-size: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: gray;
}
.modal-content:focus,
.prod-desk-size-container:focus,
.prod-desk-size:focus,
.modal-header:focus,
.modal-dialog:focus,
.modal:focus {
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade show" id="modal-desk-product" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title">HAWAIIAN</h5><br>
     <p class="modal-desc">Ham, pineapple,corn and mozzarella cheese</p>
     <div class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-body mb-2">
          <h6 class="modal-desk-product-title font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-left">What size are you after?</h6>
     <hr>
                <div class="prod-desk-size row text-left" id="prod-desk-size" data-toggle="buttons">
         <label class="prod-desk-size-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Small
                               <input type="radio" name="prod-desk-size-radio" checked>
                               <span class="gold-check rounded-circle"></span>
                           </label>
         
         <label class="prod-desk-size-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Medium
                               <input type="radio" name="prod-desk-size-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check rounded-circle"></span>
                           </label>
         
         <label class="prod-desk-size-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Large
                               <input type="radio" name="prod-desk-size-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check rounded-circle"></span>
                           </label>
         
         <label class="prod-desk-size-container col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">Seriously Large
                               <input type="radio" name="prod-desk-size-radio">
                               <span class="gold-check rounded-circle"></span>
                           </label>
      </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```